# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL....(jax-ws)

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have created a simple jax-ws web service and deployed it successfully.
Then I created one client(jax-ws), but while running I am receiving the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL  
at: file:./WEB-INF/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl. It failed with:.\WEB-INF\wsdl\HelloService.wsdl
```

But if I create the client (apache) for the same wsdl it is working. Please help.

**This is the client file.**
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

        HelloPortProxy obj = new HelloPortProxy();
        System.out.println(obj.sayhello("Everyone"));
        System.out.println("Count:"+obj.getCheckVal());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

So whats not clear to you? The exception: `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL` clearly says to you that your web service's `WSDL` is not accessible within this path: `/WEB-INF/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl`.

If you've deployed your web service and you are able to access it through `URL`. For e.g.: `http://somehost/somepath/YourService?wsdl` than create a `JAX-WS` client like this:

```
try {        
    final String username = "someusername";
    final String password = "somepassword";
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                    username,
                    password.toCharArray());
        }
    });
    URL url = new URL("");
    QName qname = new QName("http://somehost/somepath/YourService?wsdl", "YourService");
    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
    YourService proxy = service.getPort(YourService.class);
    Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) proxy).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url.toString());
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Handle Error.
}
```

I've put the code with the basic authentication as well that you might need it in future. At the moment you can just remove it.